# Adding evenly spaced axis ticks on log axis plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I'm trying to so get a plot in Julia to show tick labels for each power of 10 on the y axis, when I run the following:

```
x = collect(LinRange(1e-15, 1e1, 1000))

plot(x, x, 
    yaxis=:log)
```

The tick marks on the y axis show only `10^(-10)` and `10^0`.
I"m not sure how to add tick mark for more powers, I guess I can use `yticks` somehow but because it's a log scale I'm not sure how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by creating a vector of powers of ten:

```
tic = 10.0 .^ collect(range(-12,2,step=1))
```

and then specify it as tick marks:

```
begin
plot(x, x, 
    yaxis=:log,
    yticks = tic)
end
```

But maybe there is a better way